# How to set two vector<unique_ptr<...>>'s equal to one another?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vector, unique-ptr

I am using Visual Studio 2012 C++ and I want to set two vectors with unique pointers equal to one another.

```
    using namespace std;
    vector<unique_ptr<Unit>> unitVector;
    vector<unique_ptr<Unit>> nonDeadUnits;

    .... (stuff added to unitVector) ....

    for (auto unit = unitVector.begin(); unit != unitVector.end(); ++unit) {
            if ((*unit)->health > 0) {
                    nonDeadUnits.push_back(*unit);
            }
    }

    unitVector.clear();
    unitVector = nonDeadUnits; // error here (see below error code)
```

I want to remove all of the units that have health less than 0, but if I try and directly remove them from the vector, I attempt to access memory that I shouldn't, killing the program. That is why I have opted to do it this way. The only problem is that unique_ptr does not allow the type of copying that I want. Here is the error:

```
    error C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 2089
```

I would like to have unique_ptr's because the vectors call sub-class methods within a for loop later on, and it helps with overriding. So how do I set the vectors equal to one another or is there a better way?

Comment: I suspect that `std::remove_if` might be your friend here. I'll try to work up an example and post it as an answer.

Comment: `unitVector = std::move(nonDeadUnits);` would fix your issue, but like Quuxplusone said, there's a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general idea is to use `std::remove_if` to swap elements within `unitsVector`, and then once all the dead units are at the end of the vector, you just chop them off.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Unit {
    int health;
};

// The non-working version.
//
// void remove_dead_units(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Unit>> &unitVector)
// {
//     std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Unit>> nonDeadUnits;
//     for (auto unit : unitVector)
//         if (unit->health > 0)
//             nonDeadUnits.push_back(unit);
//     unitVector = nonDeadUnits;
// }

void remove_dead_units(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Unit>> &unitVector)
{
    auto isDead = [](const std::unique_ptr<Unit> &u) -> bool { return (u->health <= 0); };
    auto newEnd = std::remove_if(unitVector.begin(), unitVector.end(), isDead);
    unitVector.erase(newEnd, unitVector.end());
}
```

I'm sure there are other ways to do it, hewing more closely to what you tried (**EDIT:** in fact KerrekSB just posted one, using only a single `std::move` and a `swap`); but I think the "shuffle and chop" method is more modern-C++ish.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the following logic would be simpler:

```
vector<unique_ptr<Unit>> unitVector = /* ... */;
vector<unique_ptr<Unit>> nonDeadUnits;

for (auto & p : unitvector)
{
    if (p->health > 0) { nonDeadUnits.push_back(std::move(p)); }
}

unitVector.swap(nonDeadUnits);
```

Otherwise, the standard remove-erase idiom is probably more main-stream:

```
unitVector.erase(remove_if(unitVector.begin(), unitVector.end(),
                           [](unique_ptr<Unit> const & p) -> bool { return p->health <= 0; }),
                 unitVector.end());
```

Comment: Why `swap` and not `move`?

Answer (score 1):

The fast way to do this is with `remove_if` and `erase`, but that idiom violates DRY (don't repeat yourself) and I have seen people make subtle mistakes when using it (forgetting the 2nd iterator to `erase` passing (inadequate) test cases, then failing in production!)

My solution to this kind of problem -- filtering a `std::vector` for some property -- is to write a container-based algorithm to do it for me.

```
template<typename SeqContainer, typename Lambda>
SeqContainer&& remove_erase_if( SeqContainer&& c, Lambda&& test ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto new_end = std::remove_if( begin(c), end(c), std::forward<Lambda>(test) );
  c.erase( new_end, end(c) );
  return std::forward<SeqContainer>(c);
}
```

now that you have a container based `remove_erase_if`, we can filter the list:

```
// const & is important, we don't want to copy a `unique_ptr`
remove_erase_if( unitVector, [&]( std::unique_ptr<Unit> const& unit ) {
  return (unit->health() <= 0);
});
```

... and that is it.  Everything with `health() <= 0` is removed from the `std::vector`.

Other useful container based algorithms I find I use quite often include `remove_erase` and  `sort_unique_erase` and `binary_search`.  Amusingly, while the above code works `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::deque`, I almost always use `std::vector`: but writing it to work with *any* sequential container is easier than writing it to work with a `std::vector`.

Another option for the design of these container algorithms is to take the container by value, and return it by value.  This forces some `std::move` spam, but is basically equally efficient at runtime.